# Не пропадает элемент когда <input> заполнен правильно

Tags: javascript

Задача: отслеживать поля input и удалять сообщение ошибки при выполнении условий.

Проблема в том что когда я заполняю поле inputLogin и там больше 4 символов то элемент не удаляется. И так с каждым input элементом.

```js
const mainForm = document.forms[0];
const inputLogin = mainForm.inputLogin;
const inputPassword = mainForm.inputPassword;
const inputPasswordRetype = mainForm.inputPasswordRetype;


function getError() {

    const errorMessages = [
        '* Придумайте логин', 
        '* Придумайте пароль',             
        '* Повторите придуманный пароль', 
        '* Логин должен состоять минимум из 4 символов', 
        '* Пароль должен состоять минимум из 8 символов',
        '* Вы должны правильно повторить пароль'
        ];

    const errorLength = errorMessages.slice(3, 6);

    let hasError = false;

    var i = 0;
    for (; i < 3; i++) {
        const inputElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__item')[i];
        var errorElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__error')[i];

        if(errorElem == undefined) {
            const newErrorElem = document.createElement('div');
            newErrorElem.className = 'form-registration__error';
            inputElem.after(newErrorElem)
        }
        if((i == 0 && !inputLogin.value) || (i == 1 && !inputPassword.value) || (i == 2 && !inputPasswordRetype.value)){
            errorElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__error')[i];
            errorElem.innerHTML = errorMessages[i]
            hasError = true;
        } else if ((i == 0 && inputLogin.value.length < 4) || (i == 1 && inputPassword.value.length < 8)) {
            errorElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__error')[i];
            errorElem.innerHTML = errorLength[i];
            hasError = true;
        } else if (i == 2 && inputPasswordRetype.value != inputPassword.value) {
            errorElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__error')[i];
            errorElem.innerHTML = errorLength[i];
            hasError = true;
        }
    }
    return hasError;
}


function showError() {
    mainForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
        if(getError()) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    mainForm.addEventListener('input', function() {
        const errorElem = document.querySelector('.form-registration__error');

        if (!getError()) {
            errorElem.remove();
        }
    });
}

showError()
```

```html
<form class="registration__form form-registration">
       <input value="" name="inputLogin" placeholder="Username" class="form-registration__item form-registration__login">
       <input value="" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-registration__item form-registration__password">
       <input value="" name="inputPasswordRetype" placeholder="Retype Password" type="password" class="form-registration__item form-registration__password_again">
       <div class="form-registration__item form-registration__button">
            <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Create Account</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очистить забыли для каждого инпута - вот помимо всех этих `if`, после них, если ошибок не нашлось - `if (!hasError) errorElem.innerHTML = '';`

И вот это вот не имеет смысла

```
const errorElem = document.querySelector('.form-registration__error');
if (!getError()) {
  errorElem.remove();
}
```

`errorElem` элемент c ошибкой для каждого инпута свой, а вы получаете 1 и пытаетесь удалить 1. К самой форме, допустим, событие `input` привязали и оно срабатывает(хотя у формы его нет, только у ее полей), но в плане получения и удаления оптом элементов это не сработает.

```js
const mainForm = document.forms[0];
const inputLogin = mainForm.inputLogin;
const inputPassword = mainForm.inputPassword;
const inputPasswordRetype = mainForm.inputPasswordRetype;

function getError() {

  const errorMessages = [
    '* Придумайте логин',
    '* Придумайте пароль',
    '* Повторите придуманный пароль',
    '* Логин должен состоять минимум из 4 символов',
    '* Пароль должен состоять минимум из 8 символов',
    '* Вы должны правильно повторить пароль'
  ];

  const errorLength = errorMessages.slice(3, 6);

  let hasError = false;

  var i = 0;
  for (; i < 3; i++) {
    const inputElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__item')[i];
    var errorElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__error')[i];

    if (errorElem == undefined) {
      const newErrorElem = document.createElement('div');
      newErrorElem.className = 'form-registration__error';
      inputElem.after(newErrorElem)
    }
    if ((i == 0 && !inputLogin.value) || (i == 1 && !inputPassword.value) || (i == 2 && !inputPasswordRetype.value)) {
      errorElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__error')[i];
      errorElem.innerHTML = errorMessages[i]
      hasError = true;
    } else if ((i == 0 && inputLogin.value.length < 4) || (i == 1 && inputPassword.value.length < 8)) {
      errorElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__error')[i];
      errorElem.innerHTML = errorLength[i];
      hasError = true;
    } else if (i == 2 && inputPasswordRetype.value != inputPassword.value) {
      errorElem = document.querySelectorAll('.form-registration__error')[i];
      errorElem.innerHTML = errorLength[i];
      hasError = true;
    }
    if (!hasError) errorElem.innerHTML = '';
  }

  return hasError;
}


function showError() {
  mainForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    if (getError()) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  mainForm.addEventListener('input', function() {  
    getError()
  });
}

showError()
```

```html
<form class="registration__form form-registration">
  <input value="" name="inputLogin" placeholder="Username" class="form-registration__item form-registration__login">
  <input value="" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-registration__item form-registration__password">
  <input value="" name="inputPasswordRetype" placeholder="Retype Password" type="password" class="form-registration__item form-registration__password_again">
  <div class="form-registration__item form-registration__button">
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Create Account</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ